# python-entry widget Place change is not going to happen and Label creating problem

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

the code is presented below but not relocated entry widget place, label is also not created. before entered this code [ e1.grid(row=1,column=1) ] the program working perfectly, after entering the code not working, how to handle this problem..

the program is

```
try :
import tkinter as tk # Python 3
except :
import Tkinter as tk # Python 2

def update_sum() :
# Sets the sum of values of e1 and e2 as val of e3
try :
    sum_tk.set((float(e1_tk.get().replace(' ', '')) + float(e2_tk.get().replace(' ', ''))))
except :
    pass

root.after(10, update_sum) # reschedule the event
return

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

e1_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e1's val.
e2_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e2's val.
sum_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to set e3's val.

# Entries
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e1_tk)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e2_tk)
e2.grid(row=1,column=2)
e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sum_tk)
e3.grid(row=1,column=3)

e1=Label(root,text="SL")
e1.grid(row=1,column=0)

e1.pack()
e2.pack()
e3.pack()

# Will update the sum every second 10 ms = 0.01 second it takes ms as arg.
root.after(10, update_sum)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: there are errors in your program also , you are using the variable e1 for both label and Entry widgets

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: I ran your code, and i have got all the 4 widgets mentioned here. Do not MIX `grid()` and `pack()` as it will lead to such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are using the same variable for 2 widgets and using the grid function on it**

**Grid and pack are 2 of the build-in layout managers including the place**

*We can only use one of these on a single element*

In your program you are packing `e1`,`e2`,`e3` and trying to give them a grid layout.

Also you are using `e1.grid()` twice with different column values .

```
try :
    import tkinter as tk # Python 3
except :
    import Tkinter as tk # Python 2

def update_sum() :
# Sets the sum of values of e1 and e2 as val of e3
    try :
        sum_tk.set((float(e1_tk.get().replace(' ', '')) + float(e2_tk.get().replace(' ', ''))))
    except :
        pass

    root.after(10, update_sum) # reschedule the event
    return

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

e1_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e1's val.
e2_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e2's val.
sum_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to set e3's val.

# Entries
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e1_tk)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e2_tk)
e2.grid(row=1,column=2)
e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sum_tk)
e3.grid(row=1,column=3)

e4=tk.Label(root,text="SL")
e4.grid(row=1,column=0)



# Will update the sum every second 10 ms = 0.01 second it takes ms as arg.
root.after(10, update_sum)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you explain , what you really need , Because there are variable errors in your code

Comment: i want to create labels and entry widget location changing

Comment: I have re written your code, try running it , and if you face any errors pin here else upvote it

Comment: its because of spacing , new to python?